# Correct JSON Schema for an array of items of different type

Tags: json, validation, jsonschema

I have an unordered array of JSON items.  According to the specification https://datatracker.ietf.org/doc/html/draft-zyp-json-schema-03#section-5.5 the json schema below will only validate if the objects in the array appear IN THAT ORDER.  I don't want to specify an order, just validate the objects within the array, regardless of order or number of objects.  From the spec I can't seem to understand how this is done.

```
"transactions" : {
    "type" : "array",
    "items" : [
        {
            "type" : "object",
            "properties" : {
                "type" : {
                    "type" : "string",
                    "enum" : ["BUILD", "REASSIGN"]
                }
            }
        },
        {
            "type" : "object",
            "properties" : {
                "type" : {
                    "type" : "string",
                    "enum" : ["BREAK"]
                }
            }
        }
    ]
}
```

Comment: Well, this JSON isn't even valid from the start.

Comment: Can you point me to the specific invalid part?  This is an excerpt from a much larger JSON schema file, which itself passes json lint just fine.  Perhaps there's a typo that I don't see?  I don't think that's worth a downvote - you could just suggest an edit.

Comment: Found the invalidities - side effects of when I excerpted the JSON from the larger file.

Comment: It's best if you post the fixed version as your answer (if that fixed your problem), so in case people come by this question in the future.

Comment: You can also use this site to check your JSON for issues: http://jsonlint.com/

Comment: This question has nothing to do with the minor error in the JSON you noted.  It was a specific question about JSON schema declarations, not JSON formatting - I think you might be confusing the two things.  JSON schema is a structure for defining contextual validation of JSON objects.  If you read down you'll see I've already posted (and accepted) the answer I received to this question on the JSON schema google group.

Comment: Sorry to upset you, but your comments did not reflect the fact that you understood the nature of the question.  I received answers elsewhere that addressed the actual nature of the question.

Comment: let us [continue this discussion in chat](http://chat.stackoverflow.com/rooms/27106/discussion-between-deepwinter-and-0a0d)

Answer (score 72, accepted):

I asked this same question on the JSON schema google group, and it was answered quickly.  User fge asked that I post his response here:

> Hello,
>
> The current specification is draft v4, not draft v3. More
> specifically, the validation specification is here:
>
> https://datatracker.ietf.org/doc/html/draft-fge-json-schema-validation-00
>
> The web site is not up to date, I don't know why... I'll submit a pull
> request.
>
> With draft v4 you can use this:

```
{
    "type": "array",
    "items": {
        "oneOf": [
            {"first": [ "schema", "here" ] }, 
            {"other": [ "schema": "here" ] }
        ]
    }  
}
```

> For instance, this is a schema for an array where items can be either
> strings or integers (it can be written in a more simple way though):

```
{
    "type": "array",
    "items": {
        "oneOf": [
            {"type": "string"},
            {"type": "integer"}
        ]
    }
}
```

This is the correct answer.  My corrected schema now includes:

```
"transactions" : {
    "type" : "array",
    "items" : {
        "oneOf" : [
            {
                "type" : "object",
                "properties" : {
                    "type" : {
                        "type" : "string",
                        "enum" : ["BUILD", "REASSIGN"]
                    }
                }
            },
            {
               "type" : "object",
               "properties" : {
                 "type" : {
                   "type" : "string",
                   "enum" : ["BREAK"]
                  }
               }
            }
        ]
    }
}
```

Answer (score 7):

I've been looking into this for quite a while too. But haven't been able to find a working solution. It works fine if you have only one schema eg.

```
"transactions" : {
          "type" : "array",
          "items" : 
          {
            "type" : "object",
            "properties" : {
              "type" : {
                "type" : "string",
                "enum" : ["BREAK"]
              },
          }
}
```

Then you just skip the array brackets, and use an object. However if you want to do what you are doing, there seems to be no solid answer. This is the only thing that I've found so far: http://the-long-dark-tech-time.blogspot.se/2012/12/using-json-schema-with-array-of-mixed.html

Answer (score 5):

For anyone stuck with the draft 3 schema. There is a "Type" keyword that is equivalent to the "anyOf" in draft 4:

So you can use

```
{
    "fooBar" : {
        "type" : "array",
        "items" : {
            "type" : [{
                    "type" : "object",
                    "properties" : {
                        "foo" : {                           
                            "type" : "string"
                        }
                    }
                }, {
                    "type" : "object",
                    "properties" : {
                        "bar" : {
                            "type" : "string"
                        }
                    }
                }
            ]
        }
    }
}
```

Answer (score 5):

*As a response to user Vdex:* this is not equivalent, what you wrote means that array elements occur in **this particular order** within the array.

Subject to a correct implementation, if you use [this schema validator](https://www.jsonschemavalidator.net/).

With this schema:

```
{
  "$schema": "http://json-schema.org/draft-04/schema#",
  "type": "array",
  "items": [
    {
      "type": "boolean"
    },
    {
      "type": "number"
    },
    {
      "type": "string"
    }
  ]
}
```

This JSON will be validated:

```
[
  true,
  5,
  "a",
  "6",
  "a",
  5.2
]
```

But not this one:

```
[
  5,
  true,
  "a",
  "6",
  "a",
  5.2
]
```

Thus, the objective is totally different from keywords like "oneOf".

Comment: `This JSON will be validated`. But how do you set the schema for that file?? You can't use an object and set `"$schema": "./my.schema.json"` or it's no longer valid since it's an object and not an array. Omitting this and the IDE has no schema for the file...

Answer (score 1):

In my case, I want the first element in the array has a specific format, the remain elements have another format. This is my solution:

```
my_schema = {
    "type": "object",
    "properties": {
        "token": {"type": "string"},
        "service_id": {"type": "string"},
        "promo_code": {"type": "string"},
        "path": {
            "type": "array",
            "items": [
                {
                    "type": "object",
                    "properties": {
                        "address": {"type": "string"},
                        "lat": {"type": "number"},
                        "lng": {"type": "number"}
                    },
                    "required": ["address", "lat", "lng"]
                },
                {
                    "type": "object",
                    "properties": {
                        "address": {"type": "string"},
                        "lat": {"type": "number"},
                        "lng": {"type": "number"},
                        "district_id": {"type": "number"},
                        "ward_code": {"type": "number"},
                        "weight": {"type": "number"}
                    },
                    "required": ["address","lat", "lng","ward_code", 
                                 "district_id", "weight"]
                }
            ]
        }
    },
    "required": ["token", "service_id", "path"]
}
```

The above schema means that from the second element of the path, I required the district_id, the ward_code, the weight

Comment: For me, this didn't apply a schema to objects after the second object in the path array.