# JSON Schema Nested If Then

Tags: json, schema, jsonschema

I cannot seem to find a working way of applying multiple if/then logic on an enum.

`anyOf` doesnt apply the conditional logic, but instead it says if any of them match then thats good.

`allOf` again doesnt apply the conditional logic but tests a superset of the properties/required fields.

Here is a JSON Schema example:

```
{
  "definitions": {},
  "$schema": "http://json-schema.org/draft-07/schema#",
  "$id": "http://example.com/root.json",
  "type": "object",
  "title": "The Root Schema",
  "required": [
    "type"
  ],
  "properties": {
    "type": {
      "$id": "#/properties/type",
      "enum": [
        "a",
        "b",
        "c"
      ],
      "title": "The Type"
    },
    "options": {
      "$id": "#/properties/options",
      "type": "object",
      "title": "The Options Schema",
      "oneOf": [
        {
          "if": { "properties": { "type": { "const": "a" } }
          },
          "then": {
            "required": [ "option1" ],
            "properties": {
              "option1": {
                "$id": "#/properties/options/properties/option1",
                "type": "boolean",
                "title": "The option1 Schema"
              }
            }
          }
        },
        {
          "if": { "properties": { "type": { "const": "b" } }
          },
          "then": {
            "required": [ "option2" ],
            "properties": {
              "option2": {
                "$id": "#/properties/options/properties/option2",
                "type": "boolean",
                "title": "The option2 Schema"
              }
            }
          }
        },
        {
          "if": { "properties": { "type": { "const": "c" } }
          },
          "then": {
            "required": [],
            "properties": {}
          }
        }
      ]
    }
  }
}
```

If you validate against this JSON:

```
{
  "type": "a",
  "options": {
    "option1": true
  }
}
```

It fails because `option2` is required.

If you change it to `anyOf` then it succeeds, but if you change the JSON to be invalid:

```
{
  "type": "a",
  "options": {
    "option2": false
  }
}
```

It still succeeds.

I havent managed to get nested if/then/else/if/then/else working either.

How can i perform a check where I have set of properties for each `type` and you cannot intermingle them? Is this actually possible, or should I just change my design.

Answer (score 3):

First, you can [test your schemas here](https://www.jsonschemavalidator.net/).  There are several of these sites across the internet.

Second, the `if`/`then`/`else` construct was introduced to replace a `oneOf` for these kind of enum scenarios, not be combined with it.

This subschema

```json
"if": { "properties": { "type": { "const": "a" } } },
"then": {
  "required": [ "option1" ],
  "properties": {
    "option1": {
      "$id": "#/properties/options/properties/option1",
      "type": "boolean",
      "title": "The option1 Schema"
    }
  }
}
```

doesn't actually fail when `type` is not `a`.  It merely says that *if* `type=a`, apply the `then` subschema.  It doesn't say anything about what to validate if `type` is **not** `a`, so it passes.  If you add an `else:false` to this, it'll be more in line with what you're thinking, but I encourage you to think about it differently.

Use `oneOf` *or* `if`/`then`/`else`, but not both.  I suggest changing your subschemas to use this format:

```json
{
  "properties": {
    "type": { "const": "a" },
    "option1": {
      "$id": "#/properties/options/properties/option1",
      "type": "boolean",
      "title": "The option1 Schema"
    }
  },
  "required": [ "option1" ],
}
```

This asserts that `option1` is required and must be a boolean, and that `type=a`.  If `type` is **not** `a`, this schema fails, which is what you want.

[This answer](https://stackoverflow.com/a/55232878/878701) describes what you need to do in a bit more detail.