# JSON Schema validation: Validate only single matching object out of array of objects

Tags: arrays, json, jsonschema, json-schema-validator

I need to validate a JSON using JSON schema.

Sample JSON is something like this

```
{
    "props": [
        {
            "label": "Residential",
            "attributes": {
                "housingStatus": "Own"
            }
        },
        {
            "label": "Communication",
            "attributes": {
                "canContact": "Yes"
            }
        }
    ]
}
```

Based on the **label** value I need to validate the **fields inside attributes**.

Example:

If the label value is **Residential**, then **housingStatus** field inside **attributes** should be mandatory and have the value **Own** but these validations should apply only on the object which has the label **Residential** and not on other label values like **Communication** in this case.

Same for the other label value, If the label value is **Communication**, then **canContact** field inside **attributes** should be mandatory and have the value **Yes**

I've tried to use the **contains** keyword of JSON schema but it's not working as expected and it's trying to apply these validations on other **label** with value **Communication** as well.

```
"allOf": [
  {
    "if": {
      "properties": {
        "pops": {
          "contains": {
            "properties": {
              "label": {
                "type": "string",
                "pattern": "^Residential$"
              }
            }
          }
        }
      }
    },
    "then": {
      "properties": {
        "pops": {
          "items": {
            "contains": {
              "properties": {
                "label": {
                  "type": "string",
                  "pattern": "^Residential$"
                },
                "attributes": {
                  "required": ["housingStatus"],
                  "properties": {
                    "housingStatus": {
                      "enum": ["Own"]
                    }
                  }
                }
              }
            }
          }
        }
      }
    }
  }
]
```

I really appreciate any help you can provide.

Comment: Does this answer your question? [JSON Schema Nested If Then](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/55423639/json-schema-nested-if-then)

Answer (score 0):

The `const` keyword can help simplify this type of validation. Try this:

```
{
  "$schema": "https://json-schema.org/draft/2020-12/schema",
  "properties": {
    "props": {
      "type": "array",
      "unevaluatedItems": false,
      "items": {
        "oneOf": [
          {
            "required": [ "label", "attributes" ],
            "properties": {
              "label": { "const": "Residential" },
              "attributes": {
                "required": [ "housingStatus" ],
                "unevaluatedProperties": false,
                "properties": {
                  "housingStatus": { "const": "Own" }
                }
              }
            }
          },
          {
            "required": [ "label", "attributes" ],
            "properties": {
              "label": { "const": "Communication" },
              "attributes": {
                "required": [ "canContact" ],
                "unevaluatedProperties": false,
                "properties": {
                  "canContact": { "const": "Yes" }
                }
              }
            }
          }
        ]
      }
    }
  }
}
```