# Limit type of JsonArray elements to the same type, but not limit types

Tags: json, validation, jsonschema

We have the following JSON:

```json
{ "someName" : [1,2,3,4,5] }
```

or

```json
{ "someName" : ["one","two","three"] }
```

We want to draft a JSON Schema following the [OpenAPI 3.x](https://swagger.io/specification/) specification. Our constraint: an array element can be integer or string, but all array elements must be the same type. Our schema looks like this:

```json
{
   "type": "array",
   "items": {
     "oneOf": [
        {"type": "string"},
        {"type": "integer"}
        ]                     
     }
}
```

This **does** limit the data type inside the array, but still allows to mix strings and integers in one array which we need to avoid.

<s>`{"someName" : 1, "two", "three", 4}`</s>

We looked at [this question](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/15396251/correct-json-schema-for-an-array-of-items-of-different-type), but it didn't address consistent data type

Is there a way in OpenAPI Schema to enforce uniqueness per array?

Answer (score 1, accepted):

You need to bring the `oneOf` up a level. Also, `anyOf` is a better choice in this situation. The result is the same in this case, but `anyOf` is more efficient.

```json
{
   "type": "array",
   "anyOf": [
     { "items": { "type": "string" } },
     { "items": { "type": "integer" } },
   ]                     
}
```

Edit: In response to comment ...

To work around the bug, you can try pulling the `type` into the `anyOf`. The duplication is unfortunate an will make the schema less efficient, but it will probably help get around the bug.

```json
{
  "anyOf": [
    {
      "type": "array",
      "items": { "type": "string" }
    },
    {
      "type": "array",
      "items": { "type": "integer" }
    }
  ]
}
```

Comment: Thx for the heads up. I tried this in the https://studio.apicur.io editor. It barfed with 2 (intermingled) issues: "Schema is missing array type information." and "Schema items must be present only for schemas of type 'array'."

Would you consider this as a bug in the editor or I do miss something?

Comment: reported: https://github.com/Apicurio/apicurio-studio/issues/1805

Comment: It's definitely a bug. It sounds like an attempt at linting gone wrong.